# Poltergeist ruby gem fails to process `:shift` modifier in `send_keys`

Tags: poltergeist

It appears that only the `:Shift` modifier doesn't work in Poltergeist.

**Environment**

- Poltergeist gem 1.9
- Phantomjs 2.1.1
- OSX El Cap
- Rails 4.2.6

The test code that appears to offend is:

`#page.find('#category-text').send_keys [:Shift, '.']
   page.find('#category-text').send_keys [:Alt, 'a']`

In my code, I allow both shift-. (that is, the > symbol), and *Alt-a* to perform the same function. Both keys work in the browser (Chrome 50+, OSX), but only the 2nd line above works in the test.

Elsewhere in my code and tests, `:Ctrl` works fine.

Is this something peculiar to how `:Shift` works on an MBP perhaps?

Comment: Shift is tested for in the Poltergeist test suite so it definitely should be working, although since you're calling the Capybara Node defined send_keys, you should be calling with :shift, :alt, etc (no initial capital).  Because of the way Poltergeist is written changing that won't make a difference but if you ever want to change drivers you'll be better off sticking with the all lowercase symbols.  How exactly are you checking for the shift-. combo? what events are you looking for and what fields in those events?

Comment: The JS (jQuery) check is `evt.keyCode == 190 && evt.shiftKey == true`.  The event is `keydown` in an input element. Using `:shift` instead of `:Shift` did not fix things. Note that the browser (Chrome) correctly passes the logic - i.e., a "visual" test clears it. HTH.

Comment: It's not the :shift that's the issue -- its the '.' which isn't generating the correct keyCode

Comment: This appears to be a phantomjs issue where the keycode hash doesn't include an entry for '.'  (or other punctuation marks)- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a - as a workaround you should be able to do `page.find('#category-text').send_keys [:shift, :period]`

Comment: Dang. To make this conversation more useful for future searches, should I ask why `.` doesn't work in Poltergeist, and you can answer, "use `:period` instead" (then I accept that answer)?

Comment: The thing is that it's only when combined with modifiers (:shift, :ctrl, :alt ...) so it's a combo thing - I think your question is fine - I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the :shift key specifically, it's the use of '.' in combination with any modifier (:shift, :alt. :ctrl, etc...).  The issue occurs because PhantomJS doesn't provide entries in its keyCode map for punctuation keys (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a) so they end up generating a keyCode of 0.

As a workaround you can call

```
page.find('#category-text').send_keys [:shift, :period]
```

which should provide the expected results.

**Update:**  A fix for this is now in Poltergeist master and will be in the 1.11.0 release when it happens